# What is the .kdb file extension for?

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure, openssl

I know that the [Public Key Cryptography Standards #12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) file format can be used to bundle up an OpenSSL certificate and a private key. From the linked wiki page:

> These files can be created, parsed and read out with the OpenSSL pkcs12 command.

I read in some [IBM man pages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS8JFY_7.2.0/com.ibm.license.mgmt.commands.doc/convertcertificate.html) there is a `convertcertificate` command that can convert a `.p12` file into a `.kdb` file. However, I'm not able to find any information about what a file with the `.kdb` extension is.

- Where does this file format come from?
- Why/when is it used instead of `p12`?

Comment: "The convertcertificate command is related to the License Metric Tool agent authentication process. It converts certificate files from PKCS12 format to a format supported by the security software used by the agent"

Comment: So, it's a file format used by IBM software, correct? I'm hoping to find more information about it explaining how it is used in a Public Key Infrastructure. What tools use it, why is it used. These types of things.

Comment: then you might need to contact IBM or read their documentation

Comment: The link to the documentation is what I've been trying to find

Comment: This really isn't the place to get help navigating IBM's documents. From the link you provided, it's a key database file.